# What are good settings to use for exposure bracketing?

Tags: exposure, bracketing, exposure-compensation, exposure-fusion

I take exposure-bracketed photos on the Sony NEX-5R and exposure fuse them in Photomatix.

I've found that I've had to use exposure bracketing for low-light photos, to capture the shadows without blowing the highlights.

Is that a rough guideline on how many photos I should take, and how far apart in EV should they be? I currently take three photos, at 0, +2 and -2 EV, except in low-light, when I might take 0, +1.3 or 1.7, and +3 EV. Are these good settings, or is there no rule of thumb for this?

Comment: The camera type isn't really relevant, so I think this is a duplicate of the linked question.